# ¿Qué pasa cuando en un diagrama de flujo en una decisión no hay no y no es un bucle?

Tags: diagrama-de-flujo

Verán soy novato y estoy realizando un diagrama de flujo y tengo esta situación cuando hay un if no siempre hay un else y esto lo sabemos todos pero en un diagrama de flujo no sé cómo representarlo tengo mis teorías como por ejemplo no se escribe el no solo se escribe el si pero me gustaría saber

Comment: Aclara un poco mas tu pregunta, por ejemplo, con un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 0):

El "no" realmente si lo representas en el diagrama de flujo, pero estaria dirigiendose a la proxima acción, por ejemplo mira un pequeño diagrama que te hice:

https://i.gyazo.com/c572d48b2d22954733a49d64b2e44f7c.png

Simplemente lo diriges a la próxima acción o proceso.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: se me había olvidado darte las gracias, a la próxima haré mis preguntas más claras.

Comment: De nada. No hay problema